# Получить данные из поля формы, и передать в файл обработчик

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, 
Есть  поле для загрузки файлов, нужно при помощи JavaScript взять  файл из поля ,и передать в файл обработчик php
Поле

```
<input type="file" name="jform[params][myfilevalue]" id="jform_params_file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

На чистом JavaScript не силен, но вот на jQuery загрузка файла с помощью [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) выглядела бы вот так:

```js
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="file" name="jform[params][myfilevalue]" id="jform_params_file" />
  <button class="submit">Загрузить</button>
</form>
```

Если не нужна кнопка `submit`, тогда просто замените селектор на свой и так же селектор в объекте `FormData`

Comment: а можно это сделать не по клику на кнопку "submit", а при перезагрузке страницы?, нет возможности добавить кнопку

Comment: @SerhiyBilik если при перезагрузке так тут и js не нужен тогда

Comment: ну или без клика на кнопку тогда,
без JS не обойтись , я пишу модуль на джумлу, в документации не указано как добавить файл обработчик, можно только через атрибут `onchange -С помощью этого атрибута можно вставить обработчик JavaScript который будет срабатывать при изменении данных в поле`